# How to change the image of a rectangle when clicked on it

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, events

I am writing a puzzle game where the player tries to escape the room but I encountered a problem. I am trying to change the image of a rectangle named "door" when clicked. But it doesn't change and gives a runtime error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

#### C# Code:

```
private void Rectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{           
    ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
    ib.ImageSource = (ImageSource)Resources["openImage"];           
}
```

#### XAML Code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="openImage" UriSource="açık.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="closedImage" UriSource="Kapalı.png" />
</Window.Resources>

<Rectangle x:Name="door" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="230" Margin="211,10,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown">
    <Rectangle.Stroke>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="None"/>
    </Rectangle.Stroke>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource closedImage}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify a resource named `Closed.png`, but just assigned an image file of that name to the `ImageSource` property of an Image control.

What you probably want is to define two BitmapImage resources like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="openImage" UriSource="Open.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="closedImage" UriSource="Closed.png" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and use them in XAML like this

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{StaticResource closedImage}"/>
```

and in code like this:

```
var fill = door.Fill as ImageBrush;

if (fill.ImageSource == (ImageSource)Resources["closedImage"])
{
    fill.ImageSource = (ImageSource)Resources["openImage"];
}
```

Comment: I said what you said, but it didn't work. What did I do wrong? I edited the code above.

Comment: You did not assign the new ImageBrush to the Rectangle's Fill property. You may just reuse the ImageBrush and just re-assign the ImageSource property, as show in the edited answer.